# using iif in sql query without else access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, iif

I'm writing a sql query in access using `iif` statement in where clause, in which i need to check a form in access forms.

If it is true then i need to match or filter a column. The statement I have is:

```
 And IIf(isnull(forms![abc QC]!combo45),
         null,
         w.[swt Team Member]=forms![abc QC]!combo45)
```

now when I write this then it does not work. If i remove the statement and write:

```
w.[swt Team Member]=forms![abc QC]!combo45
```

then it works fine

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
And IIf(isnull(forms![abc QC]!combo45) , TRUE, w.[swt Team Member]=forms![abc QC]!combo45)
```

The condition should be a boolean.

In your example, lets say `combo45` is blank, the condition will be translated as

```
And null
```

which is not a boolean expression.